# Unable to proceed with MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql

I am creating a database (test) of 5 tables as bellow:
1- country

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

2- region

```
CREATE TABLE `region` (
  `country_id` int NOT NULL,
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_region_country_idx` (`country_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_region_country` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

3- zone

```
CREATE TABLE `zone` (
  `country_id` int NOT NULL,
  `region_id` int NOT NULL,
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_zone_country1_idx` (`country_id`),
  KEY `fk_zone_region1_idx` (`region_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_zone_country1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_zone_region1` FOREIGN KEY (`region_id`) REFERENCES `region` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

4- community

```
CREATE TABLE `community` (
  `zone_id` int NOT NULL,
  `region_id` int NOT NULL,
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_community_zone1_idx` (`zone_id`),
  KEY `fk_community_region1_idx` (`region_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_community_region1` FOREIGN KEY (`region_id`) REFERENCES `region` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_community_zone1` FOREIGN KEY (`zone_id`) REFERENCES `zone` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

5- producer

```
CREATE TABLE `producer` (
  `country_id` int NOT NULL,
  `region_id` int NOT NULL,
  `zone_id` int NOT NULL,
  `community_id` int NOT NULL,
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `producer_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `national_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_farming_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `langue` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_size` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_producer_community1_idx` (`community_id`),
  KEY `fk_producer_zone1_idx` (`zone_id`),
  KEY `fk_producer_region1_idx` (`region_id`),
  KEY `fk_producer_country1_idx` (`country_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_producer_community1` FOREIGN KEY (`community_id`) REFERENCES `community` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_producer_country1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_producer_region1` FOREIGN KEY (`region_id`) REFERENCES `region` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_producer_zone1` FOREIGN KEY (`zone_id`) REFERENCES `zone` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

The fields country.code, region.code, zone.code, community.code are filled automatically by "triggers before insert".

My problem is that i need to write a trigger for the field "producer.producer_code" to be filled automatically. I do not know how to proceed.I want the value of the field to be a concatenation of the fieds bellow:

```
delimiter //
create trigger codeproducer before insert on producer
for each row
begin
set new.producer_code = concat(country.code, region.code, zone.code, community.code, producer.id);
end //
```

To summarize I want to concatenate values from 5 tables for a value of a field (producer_code) in one table (producer) everytime there is a new row inserted into that table.

I need help to overcome this concern. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Step 1 - edit the question and format the code so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Normalization issues aside you could create a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `producer_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `producer` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    
        DECLARE country_code varchar(45);
        DECLARE zone_code varchar(45);
        DECLARE region_code varchar(45);
        DECLARE community_code varchar(45);
    
         select code into country_code from country where id = new.country_id;
         select code into zone_code from zone where id = new.zone_id;
         select code into region_code from region where id = new.region_id;
         select code into community_code from community where id = new.community_id;


    set new.producer_code = concat(country_code, region_code, zone_code, community_code, new.id);

END
```

One drawback of the trigger above is if you rely on auto_increment in producer table new.id will always be 0. Perhaps you can fix this with an AFTER trigger though.

Also, your model has 45 chars for each code field in the parent tables, so the concatenated field (that is only 45 chars too) could be truncated.

Comment: I appreciate your reply that helps me so much. As you mentionned, new.id is always 0. I will try an AFTER trigger and come back to you.